# How to POST Highcharts Image?

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts, export

I need to create a PDF file which contains Highcharts.js chart and just wondering if there is a way to optimize the Export module to POST the image (png or jpeg) to a PHP file which I want to create the PDF files there.

As you know the exporting module normally exports the output as downloadable files but I do not want to download them just send them on the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use highchart's exporting module along with [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) Library. The [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) library Support svg rendaring.

You can use the exportApi

```
   chart.exportChart({
             url : 'export.php',
             filename: 'my-chart'
        });
```

Then use the [example script](http://pastebin.com/aU4N6WE7) a modified version from original [SVG pdf example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.phps)

Main part of the code is

`$pdf->ImageSVG` expect first parameter as `string`
Name of the SVG file or a '@' character followed by the SVG data string.

> $pdf->ImageSVG("@".$_POST['svg'], $x=15, $y=30, $w=200);

Happy coding!!

**NB: You need to download the TCPDF library**