# POST svg output from HighCharts to an internal server

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to create a client side function using HighCharts, that will output the plot from HighCharts, to an SVG string. I'd then send that string in a POST to a server controller (PHP) in this case, and render that SVG to pdf with tcpdf.

The rendering part is working fine, with this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308331/how-to-post-highcharts-image) - unfortunately the help there looks like it is relying on the HighCharts server package (export.php), not a custom built server.

Is it possible to grab the SVG output from the chart, then place it in an AJAX POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getSVG` method from `offline-exporting` module:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    exporting: {
        fallbackToExportServer: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }]
});

var svg = chart.getSVG();

document.getElementById("chartSVG").innerHTML = svg;
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ez27ng51/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export

Comment: I don't have 15 rep points so I can't publicly upvote your answer.